# How to add/remove properties to object in runtime in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know how to add/ remove properties to object at run time in javascript? How to achieve this in javascript ?

Comment: Could you please give an example of your object and the properties you want to add or remove, also it could be helpful if you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL :- I have an json object with 4 elements and i want to add another element like index or any other element before using the Json object. how can i achieve this. and same for deleting element also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your object is `myobj`

then you can add a member like this

`myobj.myvar = value;` or `myobj["myvar"] = value;`

and remove it with

`delete myobj.myvar;` or `delete myobj["myvar"];`